# store,then send the image from camera to other activity

Tags: android, image

Hi in my page there are three option to make the picture to display in the another activity. option one memory card,camera,horizontal list view of images. From this what ever the user may choose but the image should be displayed in the next activity image view. Please guide me to do further !! am just open the camera and the memory card and after that i dont know how to send it to next activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need to pass the information of the image to the next activity using Intent.

You should use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(firstActivity.this, secondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("fileName","SEE_BELOW");
startActivity(intent);
```

Option A:
if you are using an image from SDcard - replace SEE_BELOW with the actual String of the image Path.

Option B:
if you are getting the image from a ListView - use the `arg2` in the `onItemSelected` method to get the position selected in the list and pull the image from there, save it to SD, and sending the String path like in Option A.

Option C:
if you are getting the image from the camera - I would save the image to SD, and then send the String path via Intent like in Option A.

Now, in your SecondActivity, in the `onCreate` method you call:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String image = intent.getStringExtra("fileName");
```

Now in your `image` variable you have the address of the image - just set it to your imageView and you are done!

Comment: protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if (requestCode == Selectedimage && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            
   Uri pickedImage = data.getData();
   Intent send= new Intent(Selection.this,Imagepage.class);
   send.putExtra("pickedImage",pickedImage.toString());
   startActivity(send);
  }  am adding this code in the first activity  is it right ??